# Links show as white space until you mouseover in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-edge

I've got a page that has a list of categories. If you click on a category, a little javascript/css magic makes the list of items in that category appear in a 2 column grid. It works great in safari and chrome. However, in Edge, most of the time when you open a category, the items in the left column appear, but only one item in the right column appears. There's just white space where all the other items should be listed. As soon as you put the mouse over the white space, the items all appear. I can't for the life of me figure out what's happening.

You can see it in action here: http://fastfoodnutrition.org/burger-king

Or just look at this screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm getting the same problem and I have no clue about what could be causing it. Thanks

Comment: No. I kind of gave up. I decided to have the content expanded by default on desktop and collapsed on mobile, so it likely only affects windows phone users... aka no one.